# Creating table partitions in DB2 for Z/OS

Tags: db2, ddl, zos, db2-zos

Can we create a table which is range partitioned where partition keys are not in order?
For eg.

```
PARTITION 00001 ENDING AT ('2018-07-02') INCLUSIVE 

PARTITION 00002 ENDING AT ('2018-07-03') INCLUSIVE 

PARTITION 00003 ENDING AT ('2018-07-08') INCLUSIVE 

PARTITION 00004 ENDING AT ('2018-07-05') INCLUSIVE 

PARTITION 00005 ENDING AT ('2018-07-20') INCLUSIVE
```

is this a valid DDL for creating partitioned table in DB2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, partitions must be "in order". [See here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtable.html) for more detail (search for `partition-element`). I've highlighted the relevant part.

> The key values are subject to the following rules:
>
> - The first value corresponds to the first column of the key, the second value to the second column, and so on. Using fewer values than
>     there are columns in the key has the same effect as using the highest
>     or lowest values for the omitted columns, depending on whether they
>     are ascending or descending.
> - **The highest value of the key in any partition must be lower than the highest value of the key in the next partition for ascending
>     cases.**
> - The values specified for the last partition are enforced. The value specified for the last partition is the highest value of the key
>     that can be placed in the table. Any key values greater than the value
>     specified for the last partition are out of range.
> - If the concatenation of all the values exceeds 255 bytes, only the first 255 bytes are considered.
> - If a key includes a ROWID column or a column with a distinct type that is based on a ROWID data type, 17 bytes of the constant that is
>     specified for the corresponding ROWID column are considered.
> - If a null value is specified for the partitioning key and the key is ascending, an error is returned unless MAXVALUE is specified. If
>     the key is descending, an error is returned unless MINVALUE is
>     specified.

Comment: Thank you so much!